# lighttpd server-status blank host and uri

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-web-services, lighttpd

Looking at the server-status on lighttpd, running behind a AWS load balancer, I'm seeing some long-lived (up to around 60 seconds) requests, in a "read" state with a blank host and blank URI. What does this mean, and is this anything to be concerned about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [ELBs keep TCP connections open to the back-end instances](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=307851) and pass requests through that TCP connection.  This lowers latency for requests because they don't have to wait for a new connection to be opened up.  The number of open connections scales up and down with the number of requests the ELBs are passing through to the back-end instances.

It can potentially cause problems if you have multiple ELBs pointing to the same instance and you have a limited number of allowed connections as one ELB can be holding a connection open while another is not able to make a new connection.  This situation is, however, a bit of an edge case and is probably an indication that you need more capacity.